# How to make multiple joins using Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

```
User::with(array('post'=>function($query){
    $query->select('id','user_id');
}))->get();
```

How would it be the syntax for multiple joins? I need to do this with 3 joins and 1 where condition.

Comment: care to post your model? the way you retrieve a single *join* is good - you should start from it. the `::with($parameter)` method accepts array (and string) parameter, so you could do `User::with(array('post' => ..., 'rel2' => ...., 'rel3' => ....., .....)->where('someField', 'someValue')->get()` should work. look at the [api](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_with) and [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L731). and dont forget the magic of *dot* for nesting relations.

Comment: The way you're doing that - there won't be any joins done on SQL level. There will be 2 SQL queries run - one to fetch the user and one to load their posts.

Comment: You should use `whereHas()` instead. Or simply `has()` more info [here.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) But you could also just keep by the basics and use the simple `join()` [here.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins) It realy depends on what you preffer to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that in your User Model:

```
public static function wherePost(\App\Post $post) {

    return static::leftJoin(
        'posts',
        'user.id', '=', 'posts.user_id'
    )
    // ... more joins
    ->where('posts.id', $post->id)
    ->select(with(new static)->getTable().'.*');
}
```

than you can get the user from a specific post like that:
`$user = User::wherePost($post);`